# Markdown support for URLs without a protocol

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, hyperlinks

If this does not classify as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) (probably [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) anyway), then I would like to present this as a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) for convenience when copy-pasting certain URLs.

The `[Title](URL)` markdown does not recognize URLs that are missing a scheme/protocol. For example:

```
[Crittercism](www.crittercism.com/register?codez=ihdqcwduji)
```

I know [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) and [RFC 3305](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3305) would not consider this as a *valid* URL (due to the lack of a scheme), but it would be nice if the Markdown engine converted this to a hyperlink anyway because of the `[Title](URL)` directive.

The logic seems fairly straightforward: If whatever is inside the `( )` does not start with a valid scheme (Here's a full list of [*Official IANA Uniform Resource Identifier Schemes*](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes.html)), then prepend `http://` to the text inside `( )`.  Or, to cut out most false-positives, prepend  *only* to URLs starting with `www` (no scheme).

## Example

**Without** `http://` it shows the title, but no clicky linky:

*Crittercism - Real Time Crash Reports for iOS & Android Apps!*

```
[Crittercism - ...](www.crittercism.com/register?codez=ihdqcwduji)
```

**With** `http://` it works as intended:

*[Crittercism - Real Time Crash Reports for iOS & Android Apps!](http://www.crittercism.com/register?codez=ihdqcwduji)*

```
[Crittercism - ...](http://www.crittercism.com/register?codez=ihdqcwduji)
```

Comment: What problem does this solve? If you're being lazy/efficient in your link adding—or somehow don't know about `http://`—you're almost certainly copy-pasting URLS from address bars/hyperlinks and would always have the correct scheme anyway. No UA that I know of drops the `http://` when copying a URL.

Comment: @M The main problem is that the markdown kind-of half parses it and makes it *appear* that the url was converted properly b/c it only shows the text from the `[]` and I figure it would take maybe 5 minutes to implement a fix.  Not a huge benefit, but a quick fix so why not ).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The `[TITLE](URL)` markdown does not recognize urls that are missing a scheme/protocol

If you mean absolute/external URLs that start with a domain component, well, neither does the `href` attribute in HTML. The protocol is required for absolute URLs, otherwise they'll just be treated as relative URLs which, for this particular site, end up ignored and not rendered as links.

I see no reason Markdown should allow something that HTML doesn't.

If you insist on leaving out the protocol, the syntax for protocol-relative URLs includes the double slashes:

```
[Crittercism - ...](//www.crittercism.com/register?codez=ihdqcwduji)
```

[Crittercism - Real Time Crash Reports for iOS & Android Apps!](//www.crittercism.com/register?codez=ihdqcwduji)

Comment: `//` sounds like a bad idea. I think it'll break once SO allows https, but the other site doesn't.

Comment: Thats actually pretty cool that you can leave out the protocol and still include the root // and it works.  I guess I'll just have to be less lazy and double check the urls after pasting them in ).

Comment: Markdown should not allow something that HTML doesn't? Well, it's for documenting - I'd like to have plain hostname there without a protocol to enable people to copy it simply with a right click and tools like putty do not want protocol filled in... \\_(-.-)_/