# Markdown link recognition w/o 'http://'

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Markdown support for URLs without a protocol](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121293/markdown-support-for-urls-without-a-protocol)

Why does the Markdown engine used by SE *require* links to start with `http://`?

It's a good practice, sure, but why not make it a wee bit more friendly by automatically assuming HTTP as the default protocol if it's not specified?

`[Example](http://www.example.com)` renders as [Example](http://www.example.com) but
`[Example](www.example.com)` renders as Example

Answer (score 1):

What about `ftp://` links? `mailto:`, `gopher:`, any other protocol? Don't try and second-guess what the editor wants, don't set a default.

Explicit is better than implicit, better to not link than to assume a default.

Comment: Read my question, I said and now quote: "automatically assuming HTTP as the default protocol *if it's not specified*"

Comment: @YatharthROCK: Yes, I know. And my answer is: No, because explicit is better than implicit, I don't want assumptions to be made.

Comment: It doesn't even recognize `mailto:` and `gopher:`, I just tried

Comment: Are answer owners automatically notified of _any_ comments on their answer or something? B'coz I see my mentions of you stripped out

Comment: I am automatically notified, yes. Interesting that some protocols are stripped out.

Comment: Would you argue the same thing for your browser address bar? Would you _really_ prefer typing `http://www.stackexhange.com/` rather than just `stackexhange.com`? Also, in this system, your browser can also predict what you're typing with just 2 or 3 charsacters (`sta...` instead of 14 (`http://www.sta...`)

Comment: @YatharthROCK: My browser can assume a lot more context; it's a *web* browser, after all, so that's not entirely a fair comparison. :-) As for auto-completion, that because you've built up a history with your browser (more context).

Comment: I meant as in that since it predicts based on the first few _unique_ characters, the assuming case would require a lot less typing (as it avoids the identical, but 'mandatory' `http://www.`)

Comment: BTW, what's the use of adding `www.` before the domain name? Does it even mean anything other than _'go to the main server'_ instead of a dedicated one (e.g., _plus_.google.com/)

Comment: Your browser never adds the `www.` if the domain without it would work too. The `domain.com` server might redirect you to `www.domain.com`, or your browser my automatically try `www.domain.com` if `domain.com` doesn't work, but it is not the same thing at all.

Comment: `www.domain.com` and `domain.com` are *distinct* domain names. The `www.` prefix is a de-facto standard, reflecting the type of protocol served by that domain. Compare that to `ftp.domain.com` and `smtp.domain.com` or `mail.domain.com`.

Comment: This standard predates the dominance of HTTP. There was once an internet without the World Wide Web, where you used telnet, ftp, email, etc. to communicate.

Comment: Ohhh, so it depends how your server is configured or something

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Those schemes you mentioned aren't even supported: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71108/159916

Comment: @Pacerier: I said nothing about schemes. URIs came with the web. I only mentioned *host names*.

Comment: @Pacerier: ah, not the comments, you are referring to the answer...

Comment: @Pacerier: so `ftp://` **is** supported, and I do think more schemes should be enabled. `email:` springs to mind here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Yea, there are other useful schemes as well.